# Examples for multi-input Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, image-classification, computer-vision

I want to create a multi inputs Convolutional Neural Network (cnn) that takes two inputs and produces one output of the inputs class by using **Keras**. I searched for resources that explain multi inputs cnn, but only found brief explanations. I need examples for **multi-inputs cnn for images classification**.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399299/keras-python-multi-image-input-shape-error/44407904#44407904 check this post